# Geometric interpretation of Ricci tensor acting on two vectors?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature, general-relativity

I've been looking into the geometric interpretation of the Ricci tensor, and the standard idea is that, for example in 3D, $Ricci(u,u)$ corresponds to the rate of change of volumes in the direction u due to curvature.

Now, as alluded to in the answer to [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/175498/what-does-ricci-tensor-do-with-two-vectors) question, $Ricci(u,v)$, where $u$ and $v$ are distinct vectors, can be solved for using the polarization identity, i.e.:

$Ricci(u+v,u+v) = Ricci(u,u) + Ricci(v,v) + 2{\cdot}Ricci(u,v)$.

So you could say that $2{\cdot}Ricci(u,v)$ takes care of the extra volume growth along the vector $u + v$ that can't be obtained by merely summing $Ricci(u,u)$ and $Ricci(v,v)$.

Unfortunately, at the moment, this means very little to me geometrically.

Is there a more direct, concrete, and less hand-wavey way to understand $Ricci(u,v)$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Loosely, I think of it as the shear term which gives you some indication of how it disrupts the orthogonality of the system.

Comment: Cool! Any quantitative equivalent of that? Perhaps a relationship between the metric and Ricci(u,v)?